# Using JSON_encode to send response message to HTTP Post request not working

Tags: php, json, http-headers, afnetworking, mime-types

I have some PHP code that provides an endpoint API for HTTP Post requests from an App.
It receives and decodes a JSON bundle, explodes it into a number of parameters, calls an activation function and then returns a JSON_encoded response message.

Nearly always, my code is working properly. However, in some repeatable situations, my App receives an error message via AFNetworking ('The operation couldn't be completed (Cocoa error 3840)) - this means that the response message was not correctly encoded as JSON.

In fact, I find that no message was sent back at all.

So I checked my code to make sure the response message was correctly returned from the activation function. I also used the json_last_error function to check for any encoding errors. It seems that the response message is correctly received and encodes without errors (I send a status email to check everything and it shows a correct response message and no json_encoding errors). But then it doesn't seem to be returned in response to the HTTP Post request ..

Hope my problem is clear. I'm wondering if I've done something to interrupt header('Content-Type: application/json;) so that it doesn't return the JSON message?

Any ideas?

```
<?php
Header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF8');

//read the POST payload
$payload = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

//get barcode from payload 
$barcode = $payload['barcode'];
$barcodeParts = explode("/",$barcode);

$root = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
require_once("$root/admin/addToDatabase.php");
require_once("$root/core/mail/sendMail.php");

$OrgPath   = getOrgPath($barcodeParts[2]);
$PromoPath = getPromoPath($barcodeParts[3]);
$PassID    = $barcodeParts[4];

$PromoName = getPromoName($barcodeParts[3]);

require_once("$root/org/$OrgPath/$PromoPath/activatePass.php");

$ActivationMsg = activatePass($PassID);

print json_encode(array("msg"=>$ActivationMsg));
$error = json_last_error();

sendStatusMail ("info@BLAHBLAH.com", "BLAHBLAH", 
                "info@BLAHBLAH.com", "BLAHBLAH", 
                "New Pass activation for $PromoName", 
                "A $PromoName (PassID = $PassID) has been activated with message: $ActivationMsg (Error: $error)");

flush();

exit();

?>
```

Comment: What does the output of `json_encode` look like?  (You can look at `operation.responseString` in AFNetworking to see what the client is actually dealing with.)  Does `$ActivationMsg` actually have a value?

Comment: $ActivationMsg always shows the right message. $error always returns zero. Everthing seems to be OK but the response is not getting returned to the HTTP Post request .. And most of the time my code is working perfectly ..